# Maintain position of item in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

I'd like to have a slide in a beamer presentation like this, but with two little differences:

1) the items have to be in the same point and not go away in the frame. For this I tried to use **overlayarea** but with no result;

2) the arrow in the picture with airfoil are too big, I'd like to have arrows less bigger.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareSIUnit\cavalli{hp}
\usepackage{subfig}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.5.1}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{somma} = [circle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1\textheight}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> 1
\item<2-> 2
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{blue}{3}
\item \textcolor{red}{4}
\end{enumerate}
\item<3-> 5
\begin{enumerate}
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (xrotor) [startstop] {1};
\node (output) [startstop, right of=xrotor, xshift=2cm] {1};
\node (velivolo) [startstop, below of=output, yshift=-2cm] {1};
\node (prestazioni) [startstop, left of=velivolo, xshift=-2cm] {1};
\node (input) [startstop, left of=xrotor, xshift=-2cm] {1};
\node (generale) [startstop, left of=input, xshift=-3cm] {1};
\node (progetto) [startstop, below of=generale] {1};
\node (naca) [startstop, above of=generale] {1};
\draw[arrow] (xrotor) -- (output);
\draw[arrow] (output) -- (velivolo);
\draw[arrow] (velivolo) -- (prestazioni);
\draw[arrow] (prestazioni) -| (progetto);
\draw[arrow] (generale) -- (input);
\draw[arrow] (progetto) -| (input);
\draw[arrow] (naca) -| (input);
\draw[arrow] (input) -- (xrotor);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\only<1|handout:0>{\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
% profilo
\draw [] plot [smooth, tension=1, rotate=20, xshift=-100, yshift=0] coordinates {(0, 0) (4, .4) (6, 0) (4, -.2) (0, 0)};
\draw [dashed, rotate=20, xshift=-100, yshift=0] (-.4, 0) -- (7.4, 0);
% velocità
\draw [latex-] (0, 0) -- +(3, 0);
\draw [latex-] (3, 0) -- +(0, .6);
\draw [latex-] (0, 0) -- (3, .6);
\def\PHI{11.3099}
\draw [latex-latex] (0, 0) +(0:2) arc (0:\PHI:2);
\draw [latex-latex] (0, 0) +(\PHI:2.7) arc (\PHI:20:2.7);
\draw [latex-latex] (0, 0) +(0:3.5) arc (0:20:3.5);
% assi di riferimento
\draw [thin] (-4, 0) -- (0, 0);
\draw [thin, ->] (0, -1) -- (0, 3.2);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\only<2|handout:0>{\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.style={fill=white}]
    \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false, tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, font=\tiny}, width=.4\textwidth, ylabel near ticks, ylabel shift={-8pt}, xlabel near ticks, xlabel shift={-6.5pt}, xmin=10, xmax=120, ymin=0, ymax=100, width=5cm]
\addplot [black, thick, domain=10:120, samples=100] ({\x}, {(0.5*1.225*(\x)^3*20.2*0.0114+2*0.03435*8829^2/(1.225*\x*20.2))/745.7});
        \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:35,20);
    \end{axis}
    \node[pin={[pin distance=2cm]3:{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left,trim axis right]
            \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false, tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, font=\tiny}, xmin=25, xmax=50,
            no markers,
                    grid=major,
                    every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
                    tiny]
\addplot [black, thick, domain=25:50, samples=100] ({\x}, {(0.5*1.225*(\x)^3*20.2*0.0114+2*0.03435*8829^2/(1.225*\x*20.2))/745.7});
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }},draw,circle,minimum size=0.5cm] at (spypoint) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]<3>{image.jpg}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

OFF: someone could tell me how to do in tex.stackexchange a code to print the exact result of latex?

Comment: Please do not ask multiple unrelated questions in one question. Concerning 1) would `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]` be a solution?

Comment: Concerning your off-topic question: just take a screenshot and add the image. For further reading maybe have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1273/36296

Comment: Yes, the [..., T] is a solution for this problem, but I prefer to have more space above the first line.

Comment: Than add a `\vspace{1cm}` above the `columns`?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to align the bullet points at a constant height is to top align the columns with `[onlytextwidth,T]`. The reduced space at the top can be compensated with a `\vspace{}` of adequate length.

With that approach you probably don't need the `overlayarea` any more, but as your code is not very structured, I did not want to dig through it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareSIUnit\cavalli{hp}
\usepackage{subfig}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.5.1}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white}}
\tikzset{somma/.style={circle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white}}
\tikzset{arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1\textheight}
    \vspace{1cm}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> 1
\item<2-> 2
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{blue}{3}
\item \textcolor{red}{4}
\end{enumerate}
\item<3-> 5
\begin{enumerate}
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (xrotor) [startstop] {1};
\node (output) [startstop, right of=xrotor, xshift=2cm] {1};
\node (velivolo) [startstop, below of=output, yshift=-2cm] {1};
\node (prestazioni) [startstop, left of=velivolo, xshift=-2cm] {1};
\node (input) [startstop, left of=xrotor, xshift=-2cm] {1};
\node (generale) [startstop, left of=input, xshift=-3cm] {1};
\node (progetto) [startstop, below of=generale] {1};
\node (naca) [startstop, above of=generale] {1};
\draw[arrow] (xrotor) -- (output);
\draw[arrow] (output) -- (velivolo);
\draw[arrow] (velivolo) -- (prestazioni);
\draw[arrow] (prestazioni) -| (progetto);
\draw[arrow] (generale) -- (input);
\draw[arrow] (progetto) -| (input);
\draw[arrow] (naca) -| (input);
\draw[arrow] (input) -- (xrotor);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\only<1|handout:0>{\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
% profilo
\draw [] plot [smooth, tension=1, rotate=20, xshift=-100, yshift=0] coordinates {(0, 0) (4, .4) (6, 0) (4, -.2) (0, 0)};
\draw [dashed, rotate=20, xshift=-100, yshift=0] (-.4, 0) -- (7.4, 0);
% velocità
\draw [latex-] (0, 0) -- +(3, 0);
\draw [latex-] (3, 0) -- +(0, .6);
\draw [latex-] (0, 0) -- (3, .6);
\def\PHI{11.3099}
\draw [latex-latex] (0, 0) +(0:2) arc (0:\PHI:2);
\draw [latex-latex] (0, 0) +(\PHI:2.7) arc (\PHI:20:2.7);
\draw [latex-latex] (0, 0) +(0:3.5) arc (0:20:3.5);
% assi di riferimento
\draw [thin] (-4, 0) -- (0, 0);
\draw [thin, ->] (0, -1) -- (0, 3.2);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\only<2|handout:0>{\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.style={fill=white}]
    \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false, tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, font=\tiny}, width=.4\textwidth, ylabel near ticks, ylabel shift={-8pt}, xlabel near ticks, xlabel shift={-6.5pt}, xmin=10, xmax=120, ymin=0, ymax=100, width=5cm]
\addplot [black, thick, domain=10:120, samples=100] ({\x}, {(0.5*1.225*(\x)^3*20.2*0.0114+2*0.03435*8829^2/(1.225*\x*20.2))/745.7});
        \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:35,20);
    \end{axis}
    \node[pin={[pin distance=2cm]3:{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left,trim axis right]
            \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false, tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, font=\tiny}, xmin=25, xmax=50,
            no markers,
                    grid=major,
                    every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
                    tiny]
\addplot [black, thick, domain=25:50, samples=100] ({\x}, {(0.5*1.225*(\x)^3*20.2*0.0114+2*0.03435*8829^2/(1.225*\x*20.2))/745.7});
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }},draw,circle,minimum size=0.5cm] at (spypoint) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\centering
\includegraphics<3>[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```